# I am facing issues while reading an excel file having lot of cell formulas using Apache POI library n java

Tags: java, spring-boot, excel-formula, apache-poi, out-of-memory

I am trying to read an excel file of about 32 MB using Apache POI Library (v3.17) in java. One of the sheet in the file is having lot of cell formulas(around 2000 rows across 40 columns). When i run my spring boot application, the execution goes for around 7-8 minutes, then it threw out of memory exception: java heap space.
I tried increasing the heap size to 7 GB for the run, it didn't help either.
Here's the code snippet where i am trying to read the file.

```
XSSFWorkbook resultBook = new XSSFWorkbook(newFile("C:\\Users\\dummyUser\\Downloads\\OverviewFile").getAbsolutePath());
LOGGER.info("Inside ExcelWorkbook");

XSSFSheet resultSheet = resultBook.getSheet("Sheet1");
LOGGER.info("Inside ExcelSheet");
```

Here's the screenshot of the console log when i ran the application,
[image: Error in console log for the run]

Comment: Perhaps you should rephrase your question. As it stands, it could very well be closed for being "opinion based" (The title is "Is apache POI library in Java is the best approach to read an excel file having lot of cell formulas?"). However, you actually have a "real" question in there, so try to remove the "is this the best approach" part.

Comment: Read it streaming instead of reading it all at once. Which is also explained on the [Apache POI website](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/limitations.html).

Comment: Thank you for the solution but I already read the file streaming by using SXSSFWorkbook, it still didn't work.

Comment: You can't read using `SXSSFWorkbook` because `SXSSFWorkbook` is for writing only. The streaming reading approach is this: https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api. Or try using https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader.